# Operator overloading(confusion why exactly this operator is called) C++

Tags: c++

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class X {
public:
    int x;
    X(int x=6) : x{x} {}
    void print() {cout << x;}
    X operator+(int rop) const {
        return rop + x;
    }
    int operator+(const X& rop)const {
        return x+rop.x;
    }
};
X operator+(int lop, const X& x) {
    return 2*lop + x.x;
}
int main()
{
    X x;
    cout << (5+x) + (x+2);
    x.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Here we see different overloading operators, that overloads addition.
In my example for `( 5+x)` was called `2*lop + x.x;` and for (x+2) `rop + x;`(I suppose)

But I cannot really understand why(especially in the first case) for (5+x) `2*lop + x.x;` was called? And in general can you explain the differences between these overloading operators?

Comment: Because that's what you told the code to do? You overloaded `operator+` for the case where *int* + *X* - the order of operands is important

Comment: @UnholySheep I didn't code that. That's why I ams asking:)

Comment: if it isnt your code you should say where it is coming from

Comment: Whoever wrote this code should feel *ashamed*. `+` should be commutative. Mixing member and non-member `+` is somewhat bad, but having return types such that `x + x + x + 1` uses 3 different functions? *disgusting*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operators are all different:

One is for `X + int` / `X.operator+(int)` :

```
X operator+(int rop) const {
    return rop + x;
}
```

The next for `X + X` / `X.operator+(X)` :

```
int operator+(const X& rop)const {
    return x+rop.x;
}
```

and the last one for `int + X` (has to be a free function as there is no way to overload `int.operator+`):

```
X operator+(int lop, const X& x) {
    return 2*lop + x.x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If an operator is defined as a class member, then the left operand is the class, and the right operant is the one in the parameter list. Like:

```
X operator+(int rop) const;
```

Here when you call it, `int` should be the *right operand*.

If it is defined outside, then it's just in normal order, left the first, right the second.

Thus for `(5 + x)`, the operator defined in class `X` can't match, and the one defined outside matchs.

Answer (score 2):

Generically, `a + b` is equal to `a.operator+(b)`, if `a` is an object that have an overloaded `operator+` member function. Otherwise the compiler attempts to call `operator+(a, b)`.

For `x + 2` what is really being called is `x.operator+(2)`.

With `5 + x` that is not possible, since it's not possible to have e.g. `5.operator+(x)`. Instead the global function have to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your addition expression

```
(5+x) + (x+2)
```

without optimization compiles to

```
 x.X::operator+(2).X::operator+(operator+(5, x))
```

(at least with GCC 7.3, I suppose that the order of evaluation of `5+x` and `x+2` could be reversed depending on the compiler)

`operator+(int rop)` isn't strictly necessary. It gets used for the first addition (of the int 2) because it is a better match than converting `int` to X via implicit conversion with the constructor. If you omit 
`operator+(int rop)` then you would get

```
X::X(x.X::operator+(X::X(2))).X::operator+(operator+(5, x))
```

In both cases with optimization, this all simplifies to

```
std::cout << 24;
std::cout << 6;
```